# Unicode Error in windows when writing to microsoft Excel

Tags: python, excel, unicode, web-scraping, lxml

I´ve written a scraper in Python that scrapes player data from the futbin.com website and writes it to a .csv file. I'm getting the following error, which occurs at the 214th page, www.futbin.com/17/player/214. Full trace-back:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jona_/PycharmProjects/untitled2/futbin_scraper_2.py", line 94, in <module>
    writer.writerows([prices_attributes])
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015f' in position 145: character maps to <undefined>
```

I suspect it is because of this piece of data on the page: 'Beşiktaş JK' (and others like it). I guess the weird 's' characters are unreadable for the windows console. I've tried changing my console encoding. It is currently set to utf-8, which I checked using:

```
$import sys
$print(sys.stdin.encoding)
output: utf-8

>>> print(sys.stdout.encoding)
output: cp437
```

I've also tried setting it to utf-16 using the `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-16` command, and I've installed the win-unicode-console package, but it doesn't solve my problem. For completeness, I will post the entire script below.

The problem started occuring when I added the line `league = html_tree.xpath('//td/a[@href]/text()', smart_strings=False)`. Which scrapes data from the 'Info' table on the left-hand side of the page.

There have been some other questions concerning unicode errors, and I've honestly tried every solution on here that I had the capacity to understand.

I'm using the jetbrains pycharm community edition IDE, python 3.5, on windows 10.

Any help would be appreciated

---

```
#
# This programme fetches price data and player attributes from the FIFA 17 Ultimate Team Market
# And writes them into a .csv file.

import csv
import requests
from lxml import html
import time
import os.path
import sys

#
# This creates a .csv file in a pre-specified directory to write the player data into
# Change: save_path and name_of_file
save_path = 'D:/Msc Finance/Thesis/Futbin Data/'
name_of_file = ("futbin_data")
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".csv")
outfile = open(completeName, "w", newline='', )

#
# This generates a list of futbin.com URLs to feed into the script
# Change: integers in range() to specify the amount of futbin.com player pages to parse
amount_of_players = 16300
list_of_urls = []
for i in list(range(16300)):
    id = i+1
    url = "https://www.futbin.com/17/player/{0}".format(id)
    list_of_urls.append(url)

#
# This loop finds all the player data from each url in list_of_urls and stores them into a list

for url in list_of_urls:
    responses = requests.get(url)
    html_tree = html.fromstring(responses.content)
    name = html_tree.xpath('//span[@class = "header_name"]/text()', smart_strings=False)
    prices = html_tree.xpath('//span[@class ="bin_text"]/text()', smart_strings=False)
    attributes = html_tree.xpath('//td[@class ="table-row-text"]/text()', smart_strings=False)
    league = html_tree.xpath('//td/a[@href]/text()', smart_strings=False)
    position = html_tree.xpath('//div[@class ="pcdisplay-pos"]/text()', smart_strings=False)
    rating = html_tree.xpath('//div[@class ="pcdisplay-rat"]/text()', smart_strings=False)
    pace = html_tree.xpath('//div[@class ="pcdisplay-ovr1"]/text()', smart_strings=False)
    shot = html_tree.xpath('//div[@class ="pcdisplay-ovr2"]/text()', smart_strings=False)
    passing = html_tree.xpath('//div[@class ="pcdisplay-ovr3"]/text()', smart_strings=False)
    dribble = html_tree.xpath('//div[@class ="pcdisplay-ovr4"]/text()', smart_strings=False)
    defense = html_tree.xpath('//div[@class ="pcdisplay-ovr5"]/text()', smart_strings=False)
    physique = html_tree.xpath('//div[@class ="pcdisplay-ovr6"]/text()', smart_strings=False)

    # This merges all the player data together into one big list
    prices_attributes = prices + attributes + league + position + rating + pace + shot + passing + dribble + defense + \
                        physique + name

    # This removes all instances of \n from the big list
    prices_attributes = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in prices_attributes]

    # This removes all blank spaces from the big list
    prices_attributes = [i.replace(' ', '') for i in prices_attributes]

    # In some instances the '//td[@class ="table-row-text"]/text()' Xpath from attributes returns an extra empty element
    # This 'if' statement removes the extra element to ensure all the columns in the .cvs file still align properly
    if len(prices_attributes) > 40:
        prices_attributes.pop(25)
        prices_attributes.pop(30)

    #
    # This removes all the remaining empty elements from the big list. Not(12,13,14,24,25,26) because:
    # Index numbers shift dynamically as the script removes elements from the list
    if prices_attributes:
        prices_attributes.pop(11)
        prices_attributes.pop(11)
        prices_attributes.pop(11)
        prices_attributes.pop(20)
        prices_attributes.pop(20)
        prices_attributes.pop(20)

    # Some URLs from list_of_urls no longer exist. These URLs yield empty lists: []
    # The 'if' statement below makes sure only non-empty lists are written to the Excel file
    if prices_attributes:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerows([prices_attributes])

    # This fixes the delay between queries to 0.1 seconds
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # This prints the loop's % progress into the Python Console
    sys.stdout.write("\r%d%%" % ((100/amount_of_players)*(list_of_urls.index(url)+1)))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: (1) supply the whole trace-back (2) `sys.stdout.encoding` is possibly more relevant than `sys.stdin.encoding`; please supply it

Comment: >>> import sys
>>> print(sys.stdout.encoding)
output: cp437

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jona_/PycharmProjects/untitled2/futbin_scraper_2.py", line 94, in <module>
    writer.writerows([prices_attributes])
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015f' in position 145: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Also edited in the main text for readability

Comment: Traceback shows that it is trying to encode using `cp1252` which covers a lot of "weird" characters, but not the one(s) in your data. You need to find out where it plugs in `cp1252` and plug in `utf8` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your traceback and code, you are using Python 3 and opening the output file with the default encoding.  `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is the default used, which in your case is `cp1252`.  Use `utf-8-sig` instead, but not `utf8`.  Excel assumes a file without a byte order mark (BOM) signature is the default encoding as well.

In your code, use:

```
outfile = open(completeName,'w',newline='',encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: This fixes the problem. Thank you very much.